# Saving a "Measurement File" (Trace) while debugging in C++ with GDB

Tags: c++, gdb

I am facing the following issue: In our project, we have a main class with a main method called "run". This method calls hundreds of other functions, classes etc.

We are now calling this run method in a test in a for loop multiple times, something like that:

```cpp
for(float test_time = 0; test_time < 10.0; test_time += 0.005){
    outputStruct = mainClass.run(inputStruct);
}
```

I now want to save all local variables of all functions and methods and all member variables of all included objects that are seen when this for loop is executed. And I want to have a snapshot of this for each loop iteration. So in this example, there should be like 2000 snapshots of all my variables.

Is this somehow possible? I see that GDB has some "trace" functionality, but it's not clear for me how I can tell GDB that it should save everything that was "seen" while executing the mainClass.run method. It should "only" remember the last state of each member and local variable. And when test_time increments, it can finalize the current snapshot and create a new one for the next time slot.

Is something like this possible? Since our usecase is some physics based scenario, it is every interesting to see how certain values change over time in a plot later. I don't mind what the format of the output file of GDB is, it will be parsed later anyway, as long as the information is somehow inside. Of course, the cleaner the file looks the better :).

Thank you for your support guys!

Comment: Maybe have a look at record replay debugging, but keep in mind that it has performance penalties: https://rr-project.org/ or https://undo.io/

Comment: Thank you for your answer :). I will look into it. But there is no easy way to do it in Gdb directly or?